# Reuse HTML element by referencing its ID

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am showing a list of items, with an expander that summarizes that item.  If the user chooses to delete the item, I need to show a confirmation modal with the same summary.  I would like to not recreate the HTML summary (needs to be identical), but to reshow the content by referencing the ID of that element.

Can this be done without causing some conflict because essentially there will be 2 elements with the same ID in the DOM?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just change the id to a class?

Comment: Class is fine, but how will that solve my problem?

Comment: I have a div (containing a bunch of html) on the page. I need to show that element and its contents in a modal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry if I'm just missing something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated [luissimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5768081/luissimo), you need to use a `class`. Using 2 same IDs is [wrong](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). It will work but it's false. So my opinion is the same as [luissimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5768081/luissimo).

Comment: I have content on the page. How can I use a class to reuse that html in a modal?

Comment: Use an `iFrame`